# opening an existing old asp Web Site with DB for modification

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am NOT new to programming however new to c#, asp, and visual studio. For my course project I have to take a seniors existing code and add some more functionality to it to demonstrate my ability in Software Maintenance.

Bug Tracking or is my project and I have to select from two different project however they are old Web Site template and NOT Web Application.

Found a way to open them now I just help with basic SQL settings

[all numbered images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpE5u.jpg)

Refer to picture and then read please. 2 sub-folders in the project folder, once contains code and the other contains DB files (Pic# 1-3). Pic-4 shows the `SqlConnection` ctor and Pic-5 is my problem.

Comment: @Jamiec: How is project1 an MVC project? I see no controllers and every aspx has a code-behind file associated with it. If anything, given the lack of a csproj and sln file project1 is most likely a Web Site project.

Comment: Just open the *.sln file in Visual Studio. But you should probably also make a backup copy of the two projects as that process will also upgrade the project and solution files.

Comment: Yes in the second picture (project2), there is *.sln file, and Visual Studio 2015 upgraded the project however many errors were displayed in IE, I have attached pictures to my original thread please have a look

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/cMCo5

Answer (score 1):

Both project appear to be the web forms template, and appear to be the web site template approach, which doesn't have a CSPROJ or VBPROJ file for the project.  If there is a solution, you can open it from there.  So use Visual Studio or the web developer express tools, which are free.

Comment: I have tried in Visual Studio 2015 but didnt work, please have a loot at my original thread and advise please

Comment: Yeah that sort of looks like that is what the issue is because I believe they ditched it...  Note the line where it says localhost/bug - that is how web site templates would show, as the URL...